# MPI: Pin each instance to certain cores on each node

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing, openmpi

I want to execute several instances of my program with OpenMPI 2.11. Each instance runs on its own node (-N 1) on my cluster. This works fine. I now want to pin each program-instance to the first 2 cores of its node. To do that, it looks like I need to use rankfiles. Here is my rankfile:

```
rank 0=+n0 slot=0-1 
rank 1=+n1 slot=0-1
```

This, in my opinion, should limit each program-instance to cores 0 and 1 of the local machine it runs on.
I execute mpirun like so:

```
mpirun -np 2 -N 1 -rf /my/rank/file my_program
```

But mpirun fails with this error without even executing my program:

```
Conflicting directives for mapping policy are causing the policy
to be redefined:

  New policy:   RANK_FILE
  Prior policy:  UNKNOWN

Please check that only one policy is defined.
```

What's this? Did I make a mistake in the rankfile?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a rankfile, simply use a hostfile:

```
n0 slots=n max_slots=n
n1 slots=n max_slots=n
```

Then tell Open MPI to map one process per node with two cores per process using:

```
mpiexec --hostfile hostfile --map-by ppr:1:node:PE=2 --bind-to core ...
```

`ppr:1:node:PE=2` reads as: 1 *process per resource*; resource type is *node*; 2 *processing elements* per process. You can check the actual binding by adding the `--report-bindings` option.